# get product collections more efficiently

Tags: php, magento, optimization

I'm working on a *custom magento theme* and i use this kind of code on my homepage to populate in product different blocks:

```
$selections_products_moment = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
   ->setPageSize(8)
   ->addAttributeToFilter('selection_moment', array('like' => '1'));
```

*I get 4 collection of 8 product (pagesize 8) and 2 collection of 4 product.*

On two different pc in local this works perfectly, but I get a blank page on a remote dev server.

I Think my way of getting products isn't very efficient, and i want to optimize it, but i can't get any clues, all i tried was to store `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()` in a variable, but it mess with the final results.
If someone get a clue, i'd be glad to hear it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already you use correct way.Enable error reporting in remote dev server so we can find out exact error in the page.

Add below code in index.php for enable the error reporting.

`ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: resolved my issue by checking the error, i was missing a custom attribute on the dev server, i had an error on getBackend() function when i was trying to filter by the custom filter i didn't had. Thanks for those two lines actually needed to see the issue